# How to detect different social groups in a small questionnaire dataset?

Tags: r, correlation, data-visualization, descriptive-statistics, group-differences

I work with a very small questionnaire dataset, in which perception of 10 respondents to the size of, say, an unseen population is quantified: The population is divided into eight sub-populations, and each respondent is asked to guess the minimum and maximum number of people living in each sub-population. Some social characteristics of respondents, that might affect their perception, is collected (both continuous and categorical).

I anticipate that respondents can be grouped into [two] different social groups of believers based on their perception of the population size. Indeed, this grouping of variables might reflect that, overall, the sociological profile of respondents that perceived a large size for this population differs from that of the respondents who had expressed smaller, and more realistic here, guesses.

The variables are:

```
ID   Age   Group   Education   Job   Experience   Experience_B
 1    32       L           2     P          6.0              1
 2    31      NL           3     F          0.7              1
 4    35      NL           3     F          4.5              4
 9    31      NL           3     F          4.0              2
13    34      NL           3     F          3.8              3
19    30      NL           2     P          5.0              4
20    35       L           3     P         10.0              8
21    45       L           1     F         26.0              4
22    29      NL           3     F          1.0              2
24    30       L           3     F          4.0              3
```

And, the respondents' guess of the population size in each sub-population (a= minimum, b= maximum):

```
        1a  1b  2a  2b  3a  3b  4a  4b  5a  5b  6a  6b  7a  7b  8a  8b
WAR001  20  40  30  50  50  70  10  20  20  30  50  70  15  30  5   10
WAR002  35  70  20  40  30  60  20  40  5   15  3   10  30  60  30  70
WAR004  8   13  9   12  10  17  3   7   8   11  11  21  7   14  10  20
WAR009  15  30  18  32  25  45  21  40  17  38  12  28  23  40  11  24
WAR013  20  25  25  30  35  40  8   10  10  15  45  50  25  30  0   0
WAR019  13  15  11  15  20  30  3   5   1   3   1   2   3   5   0   0
WAR020  15  30  10  18  30  50  10  15  7   10  10  15  30  35  25  35
WAR021  25  30  15  20  25  30  3   5   15  20  5   7   25  30  0   0
WAR022  7   9   8   13  10  17  4   8   6   11  9   18  6   13  9   14
WAR024  15  30  10  20  20  40  10  20  10  20  10  20  20  40  20  40
```

I was thinking of constructing a data matrix to calculate descriptive statistics and the Pearson correlation coefficients among the variables. But not sure about the best approach for grouping variables given the data. Also, I would like to visualize the social profile of the respondents in a radar-like graph, similar to this:
[image]

I guess considering my sample size, no modeling approaches could be considered. Anyhow, any suggestion is highly appreciated. Meanwhile, I would like to hear your suggestions about the best approaches available for visualization of this data in R.